# How to improve AWS EC2 startup time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have a use case where I need to start EC2 instances on-demmand, so starting fast is relevant to our users. Currently our startup time is 2 minutes on average, varing according time of the day and instance type.

We are lauching it using the NodeJS SDK and straight from our custom AMI, not using lauching templates, and we noted that smaller image sizes launch faster, but unfortunately we are unable to reduce it.

When the instance starts I have a @reboot cronjob with an application that notifies an api that the instance is ready, everything is installed in the AMI,built for this purpose based on ubuntu 18, and no hard work is done when it starts. We are measuring this startup time based as the difference of the time when it was started and the time it notified is ready.

The startup time is higher when no instances with that AMI were launched recently, suggesting that AWS has some kind of cold start in this case. We also noticed that increasing the disk size from 30gb to 45gb increased this startup from 1 min to the 2 min average that I mentioned.

What strategies may I try to reduce this startup time?

Comment: I'm going to say the real answer is to transition to a container-based workload with sufficient overhead. Docker containers can pull and start significantly faster that EC2 instances themselves.

Comment: I agree with @jordanm and would add Lambda's to the list of possibilities.

Comment: Are you running a startup script to configure the instance, or is everything installed already on the AMI? (Is it your own AMI, or a generic one?) How are you measuring the startup time -- it is until you can login, or until an application is running? More info please!

Comment: @jordanm I agree this is the definite solution, but it requires a lot of overhead since the application we are running is a little bit hard to dockerize.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I will add more details in the body of the question

Comment: Does `/var/log/syslog` give you any indication of where the time is spent? How much time elapses between the reported instance start time and the first log message?

Comment: @Parsifal Looking at the syslog I've found that the instance actually takes 1 minute to start and the application to notify another one, I guess that is a clue on what to improve. Thank you.